# Anyone knows which networking package contains winlive.h?

Tags: c++, networking

I am dealing with a c++ small game solution which contains references to winlive.h header. I'm sure it is part of a networking package, but haven't been able to track it down. It is not in windows sdk or platform sdk. Anyone may have have seen this before and can point me in the right direction?
thanks

Comment: Since google doesn't know about it, it's __very__ unlikely that this is something publicly available. Where does that solution come from? It could be a header internal to that company/organization.

Answer (score 1):

If you just comment out the #include for the missing header file (winlive.h), what function calls does the compiler complain about?  That will likely give you a hint.  It's even possible the header is not needed (and removing it will result in your code being able to compile).